# What are typical APIs, or standards to work with databases? (relational, Object and Nosql)

Tags: java, database, sqlite, hsqldb, nosql

Iam trying to make a comparsion table of some database features focused on databases  that can be used as embedded (in process databases) with Java. I would like to have there a field with APIs that are usually supported by those dbs but i dont know what exactly to search for.

At this time iam looking if it has a support for ODBC, JDBC (in relational dbs), then some remote acces API (REST, Thrift – not sure if its remote access API or what exactly it is) and in Nosql dbs i usually find only some kind of native APIs for data manipulation.

Are there any others that you could recommend me? Iam not looking for some advanced technics or third party tools etc. Only basic things that are commonly used

Comment: Can't choose between "too broad" or "primarily opinion based" as the close reason.

Answer (score 1):

All SQL databases that are used in Java processes rely on the JDBC API. ODBC is not relevant in this context and is used by processes that are not written in Java. Each Non-SQL database, including object databases, has its own API.